# jasmine test on route.data.subscribe()

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a component with 2 methods below.

How to test on ngOnInit() that method nameList() to haveBeenCalledWith(students)

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute, location: Location) { 
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data
    subscribe((data: { students: Students }) => {
       const students: Students = data.students;
       this.nameList(students);
    });
}

nameList(students: Student) {
  .....
}
```

What I have so far :

```
describe('ngOnInit', () => {
    it('should extract data from route', () => {

      component = fixture.componentInstance;

      spyOn(component.route.data, 'subscribe').and.callFake((data: { students: Students }) => { } );
      component.ngOnInit();
      fixture.detectChanges();

      expect(component.nameList).toHaveBeenCalledWith(students);

    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem is that I shouldn't spy on route.

I expect method nameList() to have been called with the right data,

so should spy on nameList() directly.

```
spyOn(component, 'nameList');
component.ngOnInit();

expect(component.nameList).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockData);
```